# Rasa Open Source: How to get a list of models

Tags: rasa

I am using rasa to build my chatbot app and am deploying it to the server. I went through the documentation at [rasa http-api](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/pages/http-api#tag/Model) and I like the ability to train models through the API. After the training is done I get the model's name and load this new model. The problem is that the training time is quite long and I can't wait for the response from the HTTP API. Is there a way for me to get the list of models afterward?
Same as here [rasa-x hhtp-api](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/pages/http-api#operation/getModels) but I don't use rasa-x

Thanks in advance ^^

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's an API command to list the trained models, but you should be able to see a list by looking at the directory where they're stored (which will be the default directory, /models, unless you specify otherwise https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/pages/http-api#operation/trainModel)